# Passing an attribute & value to a circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a Linux server that is serving up a local network application that dashboard some database based data to users. There is a server side using node.js and a web side made with vue.

I'm trying to create a simple html/CSS gauge that provides a visual of some average in the data, but right now i am stuck at just passing a value to the right attribute of a circle. My "gauge" is just different color circles overlayed and then a "mask" that is greyed out and based on the average will reveal more and more of the other circle colors. The attribute i am working on passing data to is the "stroke-dasharray" but nothing seems to be pushing through to the web page. It works if i hard code the attribute, but that obviously it needs to be dynamic.

Im new to this stuff - so my knowledge was that my script goes in a script tag in the page. is this the wrong approach?

Below i am trying to pass a stroke-dasharray to the mask circle.

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <svg id="meter">
      
            <circle id="low" r="150" cx="50%" cy="50%" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-width="60" stroke-dasharray="707, 943" fill="none"></circle> 
            <circle id="avg" r="150" cx="50%" cy="50%" stroke="#FFFF00" stroke-width="60" stroke-dasharray="471, 943" fill="none"></circle>
            <circle id="high" r="150" cx="50%" cy="50%" stroke="#008000" stroke-width="60" stroke-dasharray="236, 943" fill="none"></circle>
            <circle id="mask" r="150" cx="50%" cy="50%" stroke="#a9a9a9" stroke-width="65" fill="none"></circle>
            
          </svg>
</div>
</app-shell>
</template>

<script>
  var cf = 943;
  var semi_cf = 250;

  document.querySelector('#mask').setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", semi_cf + "," + cf);
</script>
```

Comment: Are you expecting it to update dynamically or when some data/state changes?  If so, what are you calling when that happens?

Comment: @sanjsanj Yes this excerpt is part of a larger functioning report that spits out rows of data. My hope was to be able to then calculate the 'cf' value above dynamically and push some mathematical representation of that to the stroke-dasharray for the mask if. Right now im just testing the idea and my main issue is that that attribute does not reflect in the <svg> above.

Comment: If you're sure that `setAttribute` functions works then I would suggest you are not calling that function further in your App's execution, so it isn't running again and not changing your SVG.  It's not clear from your question where/what change is occurring and how you're listening for that event, or how you're then setting the attribute again upon that change.

Comment: @sanjsanj Ok, so you helped me with that cause I dont think I was listening for it. So now I moved the code into a <script> portion of my page that listens for a button click and generates a report. The report generates but the set attribute thing doesnt push through. Maybe im using the function incorrectly?

Comment: @sanjsanj Thank you sir, it works now. Found a minor syntax error but the main problem was that I wasnt listening for it.

Comment: Firstly, go to the element inspector in your browser and manually change the value of the `#mask` element's "stroke-dasharray" attribute, does it work?

Secondly, paste that line `document.querySelector...` in the browser developer console and replace the variables with actual values.  That should have an effect, if it doesn't work then debug it in the browser until it does.

Comment: Cool, glad it's fixed, happy javascripting!